# Workflow Approve/Reject is disabled for the full controled users

Tags: workflow, 2013, approval-process

I've a workflow. When I start the approval process I'm getting e-mail but when I try to approve/reject it, the option is disabled. I've got the full control permission but nothing happens. I selected approval permission too but it was unnecessary (because it is already inside of the full control permission).

So what should I do? Thank you

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of approve reject form?

Comment: Check the 'Versioning settings' in the list. More here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196285/approve-reject-function-disabled-for-approval-workflow

Comment: It's not clear to me from reading the question what the desired behavior is. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the files are checked in before using the call out menu to approve/reject

Otherwise check permissions for the actual library to make sure you have full control and the permissions are not unique

Comment: But it is only a list item witohut any file. There is some texts in list items and There is nothing to check in. So it won't work. Thank you.

Comment: I guess it is changed. The approve/reject is completely disabled from ribbon.