# Approve/Reject Function Disabled for Approval Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, ribbon, approval

I have a simple approval workflow on our SharePoint Online site. However, the approval button is greyed out/disabled

[image: Disabled Approve/Reject Function]

I have verified all necessary permissions and I have complete control as well as contribute privileges. I am also the approver for this task so there should be no issues there. Help on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. In the settings for the document library I did this:

1. Click "Versioning Settings"
2. For "Require content approval for submitted items?" I selected "Yes"

This allowed me to approve and reject the documents in the workflow. I hope this helps others.