# workflow approve button is missing?

Tags: designer-workflow, approval-process, content-approval

The last section of the workflow , the buttons is not visible. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing this yourself?  What are your permissions?  Are you in the designated Approvers group?

If it is a permissions related matter then it could be that you do not have high enough permissions to approve the item - but perhaps you have permissions to view approval tasks.

[This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196285/approve-reject-function-disabled-for-approval-workflow) also mentions something useful for document approval, though I don't know if your workflow is connected to a Doc Library or a List.

### Updated answer

[image]
[image]

Comment: I got full control. I created a group for approvers.                                                                                    I have all permissions cuz i created this approval process.

Comment: The task has already been approved!  It says it is completed, that's why there are no buttons any more.  If you look at Active tasks (not completed), you will see the buttons.  I'll add a picture to my answer.

Comment: Did it work f_gulay?

Comment: So....did you find your buttons or not?  Did the buttons not show because the task was already complete???

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes it says that is completed. But this is not true. the mail is not sent approvers. And the workflow approved the itself . the buttons are gone.